# Google map api get direction API instead of returning route , it returns nearby place like bus stop etc

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps-api-3

We need to track user's path.
So for that we are using Google's map API --> input parameters are start location & End location to get route .
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

But in document of Google api
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults

As in document ---"end_location contains the LatLng of the destination of this leg. Because the DirectionsService calculates directions between locations by using the nearest transportation option (usually a road) at the start and end points, end_location may be different than the provided destination of this leg if, for example, a road is not near the destination."

In this API instead of returning route , it returns nearby place like bus stop etc.

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps API v3 (you have added that tag to the question)?  This `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js&v=2?sensor=false` loads the [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) (which was officially deprecated on May 19, 2010).

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. The `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js&v=2?sensor=false` is confusing (and wrong as well)

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false